# Set Product Review limit to 5

Tags: magento-1.9

Currently on the product view page, there are 10 customer review per page.

I want to set the product review to display 5 product per page.

Here's the default magento function that's giving the result:

```
$_items = $this->getReviewsCollection()->getItems();
```

How can I modify this code to set 5 review per page ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like...

```
$_items = $this->getReviewsCollection()
    ->setPageSize(5)
    ->setCurPage(1)
    ->getItems();
```

Not sure if the `setCurPage(1)` is really needed

It is important to use pagination methods **before** the collection is loaded (`getItems()`, for instance, does the load)

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I already tried that code, but its not working.
I also tried this:
<block type="page/html_pager" name="product_review_list.toolbar">
        <action method="setLimit">
      <argument name="limit" xsi:type="number">5</argument>
     </action>
    </block>
both not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `grid`:

> System > Configuration > Catalog > frontend >

`Permitted values for the number of products per page in the grid view` = **5**

`Default value for the number of products per page in the grid view` = **5**

If you use `list`, update the same in list